# Interrupting iterator in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder

The process for this task so far has been to copy and paste a value from a table to the 'select by attribute' tool, then zoom to the set of selected features, make a decision about that feature/those features, update appropriate fields, and repeat. I would like to be able to run a model that will select and zoom to selected features, allow me to update some records, then automatically select and zoom to the next set of features (based on a table).

I can build a zoom to selected feature tool. I would like to shorten the copy, paste, edit time. It seems like using an iterator would be a good way to go. Is there a way to pause an iterator in ModelBuilder to allow a user to update layer attribute values - say by prompting the user with eg a 'do you want to continue?' option. If the user says yes, MB goes to the next iteration. If the user does not say yes, can MB break from the iteration loop?

Answer (score 2):

You should consider using data driven pages.

You can Select By Attribute all the features you're interested in, and create a layer from those selected.

Then setup data driven pages on that layer, and can list by attribute and sort by attribute. When I've had to do this I'll build my query in excel from table data. You can concatenate query in column. Copy and paste Values to get rid of excel code, and Paste right into Select By Attribute window.

```
(Example Excel format: ="CRITICALINFO =" &"'"& A2 &"'"& " OR")
```

This way you can quickly create large queries.

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s90000003n000000